# SQL Column compare in the same table (self-join)

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I need a hint in order to solve this SQL (self-join) problem:

a table, with columns `value` and `category`

```
 id    ||  value || category || foo
------------------------------------
 1     ||  1     || a        || 1
 2     ||  2     || a        || 4
 3     ||  3     || a        || 2
 4     ||  0     || b        || 2
 5     ||  1     || b        || 1
 6     ||  2     || b        || 4
 7     ||  3     || b        || 2
 8     ||  4     || b        || 2
 9     ||  5     || b        || 1
10     ||  5     || b        || 4
11     ||  6     || b        || 2
12     || 99     || z        || 2
```

I would like to compare all values from category `b` and all values from category `a` and get all values that are in `b` and not in `a` or their `id`, so:

(0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6) "compare" (1,2,3) => (0,4,5,5,6)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i m looking for an "ansi sql" solution, it has to work with mysql, sqlite and postgres.

Comment: An "ANSI" solution usually doesn't work on MySQL due to it's outdated SQL implementation (`EXCEPT` comes immediately to my mind reading your problem description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tbl
WHERE
category = 'b'
AND value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE category = 'a')
```

See it live [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6a7/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

Start analyzing your task: "get all values that are in b and not in a or their id"

1. get all values > `SELECT value FROM mytable`
2. that are in b > `WHERE category = 'b'`
3. and not in a > `AND value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM mytable WHERE category = 'a')`
4. or their id - what should this mean?

Comment: "their id" = the column id ... but the sub-query was the solution. ty