# Within each row group, compare date field based on another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

For each OrderID, need to check if the DueDate for PartID-A has an earlier DueDate than PartID-B.

**Row Grouping** It appears [OVER(PARTITION)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can be used to compare rows which all have the same OrderID. Unfortunately, not even a smidgen of success so far.

**Field Comparison** Unsure if a [self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899022/sql-column-compare-in-the-same-table-self-join) used to compare one field (DueDate) based on another field (PartID). The syntax does not seem to allow such usage.

Using SQL 2012

This query pulls the data but does not group nor do a date comparison.

```
SELECT 
    SALES_DOC_NUM AS [OrderID]
    --, MAX(SALES_DOC_NUM) OVER(PARTITION BY SALES_DOC_NUM)
    , RTRIM(SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_CODE) AS [ShipToID]
    , ITEM_NUMBER AS [PartID]
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), REQ_SHIP_DATE, 110) AS [DueDate]

FROM SPV3SALESLINEITEM

WHERE (ITEM_NUMBER = '1RC-AM' 
        OR ITEM_NUMBER = '1RC-DCR')

    GROUP BY SALES_DOC_NUM, ITEM_NUMBER, SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_CODE, REQ_SHIP_DATE

    ORDER BY SALES_DOC_NUM;
```

Table data from query.

```
OrderID        ShipToID    PartID    DueDate  
SO003590       1614        DR        04-11-2016  
SO003591       0532        AM        02-25-2016  
SO003591       0532        DR        05-16-2016  
SO003592       0812        AM        02-15-2016  
SO003592       0812        DR        04-25-2016  
SO003593       2216        AM        04-11-2016  
SO003593       2216        AM        09-12-2016  
SO003593       2216        DR        04-11-2016  
SO003594       1411        AM        02-11-2016  
SO003594       1411        DR        03-21-2016  
SO003596       1065        AM        02-04-2016  
SO003596       1065        DR        06-06-2016  
SO003597       0504        AM        02-04-2016  
SO003597       0504        DR        06-06-2016
```

Comment: Your sample data and question don't jive for me.  Why is there no value called "A" or "B" in the `PartId` column?  And what are the results that you want?

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff sry for the mismatch confusion. Part-A is "AM" and Part-B is "DR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make the following assumptions:

- You want all orders were `PartId` "A" has a `DueDate` later than `PartId` "B".
- There is at most one "A" and "B" for a given order.
- You want the orders where this occurs.

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select sales_doc_num,
       max(case when partid = 'A' then duedate end) as a_duedate,
       max(case when partid = 'B' then duedate end) as b_duedate
from SPV3SALESLINEITEM si
group by sales_doc_num
having max(case when partid = 'A' then duedate end) > max(case when partid = 'B' then duedate end);
```

I'm not quite sure how this fits in with the query in the posting which has other columns and conditions not in the question.

Comment: That is perfect @gordonlinoff. Meant to remove the parts of the statement not relevant to this specific question. Appreciate you working around them.
Now seeing how a case statement can return another field and conditionally comparing them. My brain thanks you.